# Unable to store image of input type=hidden

Tags: php

I am using image cropping jquery plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Client-Side-Image-Cropping-Plugin-Awesome-Cropper.html

To work this plugin I have to use `<input id="someId" class="crop-img" type="hidden">` `( type="hidden" instead of type="file")`

And the script to instantiate,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.crop-img').awesomeCropper(
      { width:1020, height:434 , debug: true }
    );
})
```

But the problem is I'm unable to get value in php laravel framework because of `type="hidden"`, if I change it to `type="file"` I'm getting value but the cropping plugin is not working...
Help, please..

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, it doesn't have access to anything within your HTML or JavaScript realms unless you submit it back to the server. In this case, a possible approach would be to use AJAX from JavaScript. It's totally unclear from your question whether you've attempted to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this plugin saves the cropped image to that hidden input field in the form of base64 encoding. So you don't get a file type which you can send it via form submission.
What you can do is that get that data & send it to your server then there convert base64 to an image. You can get that data using JQuery like this,

```
let base64EncodedImage = $('#someId').val();
```

It will return an output which will look like this,

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAACWCAYAAAA8AXHiAAAgAElEQVR4Xuydd3xcxbm/n+19V2V3teq9S5ZcZMu9YAO2AWODaQkQQgIhvSc3uUlukpvkpocL6Z2E3sHGGPdeZMuWrN7r7mqlXWl73/19JAjcJPyuCeDEutr5S/aZec8733l2Zs6cOe8I4vF4nHeQpotHYzGCoTDRaPQdWEoU/b+kgOCdgPUXqALBELFY7P+SLom6vEMF/gosv9+PdcyG0+lEIpFgMqURDkcwpRnf9DbTMAVCISKRv+6ppoHz+XxEolHUKhUikegdupkoPtsUeB2saagazjZiNluRyaQzw9r4hB2RUMg9H7jr7+o1Dc80OP5A8O+uBYNBWlrbkEll6A2pmNLS/ipPLOTDMelGqEwibO8nqMoix6Cmv7cXfaoOs2UCBAI0yUZMRhVtDc1IkpJQKNQo5CKkEhEeuwOZPosUtQTzUC9STQZGbZyOf
```